# How to determine if integration branch contains feature branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I am doing the scary work of deleting local branches.  I fetch the latest from our integration branch:

```
git fetch origin dev
```

and then I want to compare origin/dev with feature branches locally. But I do not want to check out origin/dev. I believe the goal is to ensure the git log for origin/dev contains the tip (latest commit) of each feature branch.

The following command is not very effective on my case:

```
git branch --contains <commit-id>
```

1. it is unclear how to use a branch other than the current one.
2. I don't have the commit-id of the comparison branch, but I do have the branch name.

So I am looking for an alternative command:

```
git branch origin/dev --contains-branch <some-feature-branch>
```

is there a command that can do this?

Comment: Would a command which prints all non-merged branches help in your case? I don't have access to my other machine at the moment, but I could look up the command in my alias later and post an answer. It works for my use-case, YMMV

Comment: `git branch --no-merged upstream` is what I have. `git branch` is *not* a plumbing command, so it shouldn't be used in scripts (but it works for my use case and I only use it in a non-destrcutive manner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `git branch --contains` does is:

1. Resolve `HEAD` to a commit hash.  If you're on branch `br`, this resolves the *name* `br` to a commit hash.  (Let some variable *h* represent this hash.)
2. For all branch names:

   - Resolve the name to a commit hash.  Let's call this *b* for the branch-hash.
   - Test ancestor-ness: is *b* an ancestor of *h*?
   - If *b* **is** an ancestor of *h*, print this branch's name.

The command is now complete: it has listed the names of branches whose branch-tip commit is contained in this branch.

Your problem is very similar, but simpler.  You want to resolve the name `origin/dev` to some hash *h*.  Then, for some subset of your branch names—the feature names you care about—you want to:

- Resolve the name to a hash ID *b*.
- Test ancestor-ness: is *b* an ancestor of *h*?  (In other words: s this branch's tip commit contained within `origin/dev` by being an ancestor of the tip commit of `origin/dev`?)
- If so, print the name.

There is a command that implements this "is-ancestor" test, but it's a bit surprising: it's `git merge-base`.  The command:

```
git merge-base $b $h
```

reports success (exits zero) if $b is an ancestor of $h, and reports failure (exits nonzero) if not.  The "is ancestor" test it implements is the same one that `git branch --contains` uses so this directly provides the answer you want.

The remaining problem is to find the desired branch name(s).  The `git for-each-ref` command is literally designed to do just that.

Hence:

```
hname=origin/dev
h=$(git rev-parse $hname) || die "cannot get commit hash ID for $hname"
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short) %(objectname)' refs/heads/feature |
    while read name b; do
        if git merge-base --is-ancestor $h $b; then
            echo $name is contained within $hname
        fi
    done
```

(note: untested).  The `refs/heads/feature` here represents branches named `feature/*`; if you have a different pattern you need to match, use that different pattern, or use `refs/heads` itself and put something in the loop to skip "uninteresting" branch names, or whatever it takes.

See the documentation for [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) and [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) (and [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), for that matter) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To list the branch tips that are reachable from `origin/dev`, you can use

```
git branch --merged origin/dev
```

Note that this does list `origin/dev` if it is a local branch (which I assume is not in your case).

If you want to script around `git branch`, be warned that it is a "porcelain" command, i.e., its output format is not cast in stone and may change in a future version of Git.

Comment: cause porcelain breaks! lulz i see it now